# Actionscript 3 - Drag and Drop game with feedback, only one object working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm a newbie to Actionscript, so I'm not sure quite what the problem is with my code.

I'm creating a Flash/Actionscript game, where kids will drag and drop different food items onto the food pyramid - the modern one. All items drag and drop, however only the first item (banana_mc) creates feedback. I have no idea why this is happening, and there are no Compiler errors.

My actionscript is as follows:

```
    banana_mc.objName = "banana";
banana_mc.initX = banana_mc.x;
banana_mc.initY = banana_mc.y;
banana_mc.val = 0;

bread_mc.objName = "bread";
bread_mc.initX = bread_mc.x;
bread_mc.initY = bread_mc.y;
bread_mc.val = 0;

broccoli_mc.objName = "broccoli";
broccoli_mc.initX = broccoli_mc.x;
broccoli_mc.initY = broccoli_mc.y;
broccoli_mc.val = 0;

burger_mc.objName = "burger";
burger_mc.initX = burger_mc.x;
burger_mc.initY = burger_mc.y;
burger_mc.val = 0;

carrot_mc.objName = "carrot";
carrot_mc.initX = carrot_mc.x;
carrot_mc.initY = carrot_mc.y;
carrot_mc.val = 0;

cheese_mc.objName = "cheese";
cheese_mc.initX = cheese_mc.x;
cheese_mc.initY = cheese_mc.y;
cheese_mc.val = 0;

chips_mc.objName = "chips";
chips_mc.initX = chips_mc.x;
chips_mc.initY = chips_mc.y;
chips_mc.val = 0;

corn_mc.objName = "corn";
corn_mc.initX = corn_mc.x;
corn_mc.initY = corn_mc.y;
corn_mc.val = 0;

eggplant_mc.objName = "eggplant";
eggplant_mc.initX = eggplant_mc.x;
eggplant_mc.initY = eggplant_mc.y;
eggplant_mc.val = 0;

egg_mc.objName = "egg";
egg_mc.initX = egg_mc.x;
egg_mc.initY = egg_mc.y;
egg_mc.val = 0;


banana_mc.buttonMode = true;
bread_mc.buttonMode = true;
broccoli_mc.buttonMode = true;
burger_mc.buttonMode = true;
carrot_mc.buttonMode = true;
cheese_mc.buttonMode = true;
chips_mc.buttonMode = true;
corn_mc.buttonMode = true;
eggplant_mc.buttonMode = true;
egg_mc.buttonMode = true;

banana_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousePress);
banana_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseRelease);
bread_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousePress);
bread_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseRelease);
broccoli_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousePress);
broccoli_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseRelease);
burger_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousePress);
burger_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseRelease);
carrot_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousePress);
carrot_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseRelease);
cheese_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousePress);
cheese_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseRelease);
chips_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousePress);
chips_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseRelease);
corn_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousePress);
corn_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseRelease);
eggplant_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousePress);
eggplant_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseRelease);
egg_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousePress);
egg_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseRelease);

//Mouse Events

function mousePress(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);
    item.startDrag();

    var topPos:uint = this.numChildren - 1;
    this.setChildIndex(item, topPos);
}


function mouseRelease(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);
    item.stopDrag();

    switch (item.objName) {
        case "banana" :
            if (bottom_mc.hitTestObject(item)) {
                updateShape(item, bottom_mc);

            } else {
                info_txt.text ="WRONG!";

            }
            break;
        case "bread" :
            if (third_mc.hitTestObject(item)) {
                updateShape(item, third_mc);

            } else {
                info_txt.text ="WRONG!";

            }
            break;
        case "broccoli" :
            if (bottom_mc.hitTestObject(item)) {
                updateShape(item, bottom_mc);
            } else {
                info_txt.text ="WRONG!";

            }
            break;
            case "burger" :
            if (top_mc.hitTestObject(item)) {
                updateShape(item, top_mc);

            } else {
                info_txt.text ="WRONG!";

            }
            case "carrot" :
            if (bottom_mc.hitTestObject(item)) {
                updateShape(item, bottom_mc);

            } else {
                info_txt.text ="WRONG!";

            }
            case "cheese" :
            if (second_mc.hitTestObject(item)) {
                updateShape(item, second_mc);

            } else {
                info_txt.text ="WRONG!";

            }
            case "chips" :
            if (top_mc.hitTestObject(item)) {
                updateShape(item, top_mc);

            } else {
                info_txt.text ="WRONG!";

            }
            case "corn" :
            if (bottom_mc.hitTestObject(item)) {
                updateShape(item, bottom_mc);

            } else {
                info_txt.text ="WRONG!";

            }
        default :
            ; ;
    }
    function updateShape(item:MovieClip, bin:MovieClip):void {


    item.visible = true;
    info_txt.text ="CORRECT!";

    item.val = 1;
    resetShapes();
}

function resetShapes() {
    if ((banana_mc.val == 1)&& (bread_mc.val == 1) && (broccoli_mc.val == 1) &&(burger_mc.val == 1) &&(carrot_mc.val == 1) &&(cheese_mc.val == 1) &&(chips_mc.val == 1) &&(corn_mc.val == 1) &&(eggplant_mc.val == 1) &&(egg_mc.val == 1)){

        banana_mc.x = banana_mc.initX;
        banana_mc.y = banana_mc.initY;
        bread_mc.x = bread_mc.initX;
        bread_mc.y = bread_mc.initY;
        broccoli_mc.x = broccoli_mc.initX;
        broccoli_mc.y = broccoli_mc.initY;
        burger_mc.x = burger_mc.initX;
        burger_mc.y = burger_mc.initY;
        carrot_mc.x = carrot_mc.initX;
        carrot_mc.y = carrot_mc.initY;
        cheese_mc.x = cheese_mc.initX;
        cheese_mc.y = cheese_mc.initY;
        chips_mc.x = chips_mc.initX;
        chips_mc.y = chips_mc.initY;
        corn_mc.x = corn_mc.initX;
        corn_mc.y = corn_mc.initY;
        eggplant_mc.x = eggplant_mc.initX;
        eggplant_mc.y = eggplant_mc.initY;
        egg_mc.x = egg_mc.initX;
        egg_mc.y = egg_mc.initY;


        banana_mc.visible= true;
        bread_mc.visible= true;
        broccoli_mc.visible= true;
        burger_mc.visible= true;
        carrot_mc.visible= true;
        cheese_mc.visible= true;
        chips_mc.visible= true;
        corn_mc.visible= true;
        eggplant_mc.visible= true;
        egg_mc.visible= true;


        banana_mc.val= 0;
        bread_mc.val= 0;
        broccoli_mc.val= 0;
        burger_mc.val= 0;
        carrot_mc.val= 0;
        cheese_mc.val= 0;
        chips_mc.val= 0;
        corn_mc.val= 0;
        eggplant_mc.val= 0;
        egg_mc.val= 0;

    }
}

}
```

If anyone can please help me out, I'd really appreciate it! It's part of an assignment this week (not a coding one) so I'd really need a quick solution if possible...

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statements are configured to look for the exact string specified by your object's name. So casing matters :)
Either do a item.objName.toLocalLowercase(), change your object's name to only include lowercase letters, or change your case's to match all your object's names by capitalizing everything except banana.

Comment: I have edited the code, and put it back into the above snippet. But it still doesn't work, and now the banana object doesn't work either. I also get this error when i drag and drop an object :

TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
 at healthyeating2_fla::MainTimeline/mouseRelease()

Comment: Could you check "permit debugging" for me? If you're using adobe flash CS, it's at menu > publish settings > advanced settings. I can't tell what's causing your issue at this time, but that would help. You can also remove the toLocalLowercase() function since all of your object's names are lowercase.

Also, a great feature that would help would be the debugging tool. If you're using adobe flash cs, hit cntrl + **shift** + enter to enter debugging mode. Your test swf will stop and show the line where the error is coming from as well as current values it's handling that may be related to it.

Comment: I changed the code again, and pasted it above. 
However, debugging doesn't do anything. It doesn't show any errors in the code. Now certain objects produce feedback, and certain ones don't. But the feedback is wrong in any case. 

Would emailing the project file help?

Comment: @sm-ashed, i appreciate you need help quickly but emailing files is usually for paid effort (via-site help is free). No-one will take time-out just to do the homework of a stranger and email it back...

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to do it for me. It's done, just not working correctly. 
I appreciate the help, but I can't see any reason it's not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a useful tip to reduce code amount...

In your `function updateShape(item:MovieClip, bin:MovieClip):void` at the bottom you have:

`resetShapes();` which might be better as `resetShapes( item );`

If you provide a function parameter (*aka* function argument) like above then when you run `resetShapes` it only has to deal with current clicked item (provided as function parameter) so you can just simply write...

```
function resetShapes ( in_item : MovieClip ) : void
{
    if( in_item.val == 1)
    {
        in_item.x = in_item.initX;
        in_item.visible = true;
        in_item.val = 0;
    }
}
```

Also in your `function mouseRelease(event:MouseEvent):void` at the bottom you have `default : ; ;` this might cause problems when you try to compile so fix or remove it. What are you trying to achieve with this command? If we understand your code or logic, it's easier to give you advice.

check this **[Switch/Case tutorial article](http://then.digital/as3-switch-case.html)** for clarity...